# Set layout height

Tags: android

I have to set the layout's height on 50% but it doesn't admit `android:layout_height="0.5"`, how Can I set it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.wt.pr.ResultsActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use [android:layout_weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight) attribute as `android:layout_weight=0.5` and set your `layout_height=0dp` where

or it can be simply `android:layout_weight=1` for both

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.you have to set weight property and set height 0dp

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to switch to the new ConstraintLayout, it got options to set the height to % of the screen. Another option is to use 'layout_weight'. Since you are using a LinearLayout as your root layout you can set inner layouts' weight.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.wt.pr.ResultsActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```